# IRC Protocol - Registration to Server with Password

Tags: client, registration, telnet, irc, socks

I'm trying to write a Python IRC script. It is not connecting to my UnrealIRCD server, so I tried it with TELNET:

```
telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 6667
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
PASS MYSERVERPASS
NICK MYNICKNAME
PING :7EF7F35D
USER MyUserName 8 * :MY REALNAME
```

After this connection, it doesn't accept the registration and times out. When I try to connect via telnet to an EFnet server, for instance, this process works fine.

So, does anyone have an idea what is wrong with the registration process?

Other clients and Eggdrop Bots can connect to the server with no problem. So I don't understand why these simple protocol commands are not working.

Comment: Since other clients can connect to the server, use a packet sniffer (like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)) to see what they are doing different than you, and then adjust your commands accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this message was sent by the server:

```
PING :7EF7F35D
```

You have to reply to it, with this message:

```
PONG :7EF7F35D
```

(change the payload of the PONG to match the one in the PING)

This is probably required by the server to avoid attacks.